# $.getJSON is not fully working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a simple java-script method to call code behind using $.getJSON.

```
 function GetTrainingResults(id){
 $.getJSON("/dashboard/GetTrainingResults/", null, function(data) {
   return data;
   });
}
```

and conroller method is

```
public ActionResult GetTrainingResults()
    {
        string test = "You are there.";
        return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Its being called. but i cant get the data.it returns null.
Note : how to pass the paremeter.

Thanks

Comment: change this `null` to this `{nullData : null}` and then return it `return data.nullData;`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a callback to return a value from an Ajax request.

Something like :

```
function GetTrainingResults(id, callback){
   $.getJSON("/dashboard/GetTrainingResults/", null, callback);
}
```

Call example :

```
GetTrainingResults(yourid, function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Its the value of the id you want to get, its just an example.

Comment: Well in your original code, you define an id argument in your function but you dont use it in the function so only you know why its here and what value it needs... Defining a callback like I/@bipen did to return a value from an ajax call is working for sure :)

Comment: @RafH ...correct... :)...`so only you know why its here and what value it needs`.. nice  +1 from me :)

Comment: yes, i need to send this id rather than null, when it will work fine for null then i will replace it by id.
I will query it in my question "Note : how to pass the paremeter." :)

Answer (score 2):

that is because is ajax is ashynchronus....you can call a callback function and alert it there..

```
function GetTrainingResults(id,callback){
  $.getJSON("/dashboard/GetTrainingResults/", {'id':id}, callback);
}
```

calling  GetTrainingResults function with a callback

```
GetTrainingResults('id',function(result){
    alert(result);
})
```

> how to pass the paremeter.

you can pass parameter to you contorller in you second options of get.. i am sending id to the contorller with get method in your controller.. so you can get the id using get there